# Android Studio coverage report not run on annotated methods

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations, robolectric, powermockito

I've set up an Android Library project for unit testing. To support effective testing, I've included Robolectric and PowerMockito in my setup. This process has generally gone well until I noticed some bizarre behavior when it came to running a coverage report using Android Studio's built in tools.

The library project is making use of a custom annotation in order to facilitate aspect-oriented logging. It has a RetentionPolicy of CLASS so that it will be weaved into the class upon compilation, and the available targets are Constructors and Methods (thought we've only had success in instrumenting methods).

Something about this particular configuration is causing Android Studio to skip coverage collection entirely on any methods with this particular annotation. Here's what I've tried so far:

-Removed annotation (coverage report works, obviously logging doesn't)

-Changed annotation's RetentionPolicy to SOURCE (coverage report works, breaks aspect-oriented logging)

-Changed code coverage method from "Sampling" to "Tracing" (no effect)

-Changed coverage runner from Intellij IDEA to JaCoCo (no effect)

-Removed constructor target from annotation (no effect)

As you can see, the only solutions I've come up with that re-enable coverage also neuter the annotation. Admittedly, I only half-heartedly attempted to switch to JaCoCo (I just changed the coverage runner and set testCoverageEnabled to true in my build.gradle, which I've read may not be sufficient). Any other ideas? This isn't a deal breaker necessarily since the tests DO run, but it would be nice to have an accurate coverage report.

Comment: What library do you use for logging?

Comment: The particular logging that's interfering with the tests is actually just for devs, written out to Logcat. It's loosely based off of an aspect-oriented solution called Hugo: https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

Comment: Looks like already reported https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/issues/97

Comment: So I'm not crazy! Thanks for tracking that down!

Comment: So jacoco also instruments code for coverage reporting. I would create build type for code coverage and I would try to remove AspectJ from classpath for this build type

Comment: Did you try to get coverage for release build type? I assume it should work

Comment: Removing AspectJ from the classpath does indeed allow coverage to run successfully on the annotated methods. Testing against the release build alone was not sufficient to get coverage, I also had to comment the aspect-oriented gradle declarations and java code out. 

EDIT: Just had a chance to look at Hugo's code that you liked in the ticket. The modifications we made for simplicity was to run this on all build variants, not just the debuggable ones. That's something we can certainly correct. Thank you again!

Comment: I just made a change to exclude debuggable build variants from the compilation post-process. Running Intellij IDEA coverage report on the release flavor totally works now!

Answer (score 1):

Huge thank you to the commenter in my question. Our aspect-oriented logging code is loosely based on [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo/). The plugin that allows injection of trace logging is not run on non-debuggable build variants.

I added a similar line of code to the library's build.gradle file and switched the build variant to "release". Intellij's IDEA coverage report successfully began generating coverage information on the code it previously skipped.